# Hibernate JPA simplify code for update(),delete(),add()

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, refactoring

I created update() method which is using JPA. It looks like this:

```
public boolean update(Programy program) throws Exception {
        try {
            entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("firebird_config_file");
            entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();

            entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
            entityManager.merge(program);
            entityManager.getTransaction().commit();

            entityManager.close();
            entityManagerFactory.close();
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }
```

In my save() and delete method I am changing only one thing - merge()  -> persist() or delete(). Remaining part of code is similar as here. How can i refactor this code to simplify this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very good use-case for a pattern called [template method](https://www.baeldung.com/java-template-method-pattern).

For example, you can create an abstract class, which wraps all your boilerplate code in `perform` method:

```
abstract public class HibernateAction<T> {
    private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;
    //I'm passing EntityManagerFactory, because it should be singleton and you shouldn't
    //probably create it from scratch everytime
    public HibernateAction(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        this.entityManagerFactory = entityManagerFactory;
    }

    protected abstract T action(EntityManager entityManager, T entity);

    public boolean perform(T entity) throws Exception {
        try {
            var entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
            entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
            action(entityManager, entity); //call to action which need to be overriden
            entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
            entityManager.close();
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }   
    }
}
```

then you can just create a class which inherits `HibernateAction`:

```
public class UpdateAction extends HibernateAction<Program> {

    public UpdateAction(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        super(entityManagerFactory);
    }

    @Override
    protected Program action(EntityManager entityManager, Program entity) {
        return entityManager.merge(entity);
    }
}
```

and finally you can use it like this:

```
public boolean update(Program program) throws Exception {
    return updateAction.perform(program);
}
```

But since anonymous methods are supported in Java (since Java 8), you could also rewrite it in a little bit less verbose way using higher order functions:

```
public class HibernateAction2{ // no longer abstract

    private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

    public HibernateAction2(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        this.entityManagerFactory = entityManagerFactory;
    }

    //we expect a user to pass lambda function, which would tell us what to do with an entity manager
    public boolean perform (Consumer<EntityManager> action) throws Exception {
        try {
            var entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
            entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
            action.accept(entityManager);
            entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
            entityManager.close();
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

and then you can use it like:

```
hibernateAction2.perform(em -> em.merge(program)); //for merge

hibernateAction2.perform(em -> em.persist(program)); //for persist, etc.
```

This is called *loan pattern* or *loaner pattern* (or *bracket* in FP languages), because you "loan" entity manager from hibernateAction2 to use it to do some kind of action, but it handles all other things, like creating an object or closing connection.